Запуск ReactJS через Docker занимает очень много времени
Пытаюсь создать контейнер с реакт приложение жду уже 500 сек.. Показывает одно и тоже:
 => => sha256:708f9b01fc1a5dff70f7d40443ac7dd0ee1d0ae93202b6f305f4e3627cea7d22 0B / 43.17MB                                                          448.4s
 => => sha256:7feaa2634e51f929e9ca86765cd5579cdf0809084c80d6787166627ca2aed6d4 65.15kB / 4.09MB                                                      448.4s
 => => sha256:dc5d948bc7089eee9551a072ac758688696cf87a38dce63eb5f20b8dcdb94436 0B / 48.04MB                                                          448.4s
 => => sha256:04342be7ba7401368aca600e5ccdfd1d61ba20935bed65fd69522f28c9352822 0B / 202.24MB  

Dockerfile:
FROM node:14 as build-stage 

WORKDIR /app/frontend 

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . .

RUN npm start

Docker-compose:
  app:
    container_name: app_container
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../frontend:/app/frontend
    networks:
      - common

